# Understanding the Energy-Momentum Tensor for the Klein-Gordon Field

Tags: field-theory, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

On Peskin & Schroder's QFT Book, page 19, they give us the conserved charge associated with spatial translations (equation 2.19):
$$P^i=\int T^{0i}d^3x=-\int\pi \partial_i\phi d^3x$$
where $T^\mu_{\ \  \ \nu}$ is the energy momentum tensor:
$$T^\mu_{\ \  \ \nu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\partial_\nu \phi-L\delta^\mu_\nu$$
Where $L$ is the lagrangian density.
Now, the book doesn't actually show the intermediate steps, so I decided to try to do them myself. And although I think I am close, there is something that eludes me.

My attempt is:
Start with the Lagrangian density for the Klein-Gordon Field:
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$$
Now I plug this into the energy-momentum tensor:
$$T^\mu_{\ \  \ \nu}=\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi-\delta^\mu_\nu(\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2)$$
Now, I know that momentum corresponds to $T^{0i}$, so I raise the $\nu$ everywhere and set $\mu=0$.(Recognizing it as the time derivative)
$$T^{0\nu}=\partial_t\phi\partial^\nu\phi-(\frac{1}{2}\partial_t \phi \partial_t \phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2)$$
Now if I were to take $\nu=i$, I would find
$$T^{0i}=\partial_t\phi\partial^i\phi-(\frac{1}{2}\partial_t \phi \partial_t \phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2)$$
Lowering the index on the first term:
$$T^{0i}=-\partial_t\phi\partial_i\phi-(\frac{1}{2}\partial_t \phi \partial_t \phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2)$$
Now, the first term resembles what I am looking for, keeping in mind that $\pi=\partial_t\phi$. But I don't know how to get rid of the $1/2$ or the 2nd and third term.
What is the way forward here?

Comment: 1. $\partial \mathcal{L}/ \partial{\phi,_\mu}= \partial^\mu \phi$ (your 4th formula). 2. Summation indices should occur only twice (also 4th formula).

Comment: 1.  I Don't understand. Is that not what I did? 
2. I believe I fixed that, but it doesn't seem to have had an impact on the rest of the problem

Comment: Your factor $1/2$ is wrong. As I said, $\partial \mathcal{L} / \partial \phi,_\mu = \partial^\mu \phi$ and not $\frac{1}{2} \partial^\mu \phi$.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you meant. Sorry if this is a basic question, but I dont' understand what happened to it. since we had $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu$, Where would a factor of two come from? I would understand if it was $(\partial_\mu)^2$, but I don't see it here

Comment: $\partial (\eta^{\rho \sigma} \phi,_\rho \phi,_\sigma) / \partial \phi,_\mu = 2 \phi^{,\mu}$

Comment: I understand. Thank you! I will edit the correction in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\delta_0^{\, \, i}=0$ for $i=1,2,3$ solves your problem.